# ¿Cómo promedio variables por fila?

Tags: r, data

Quiero promediar las filas en dos columnas diferentes (`TempA` y `TempB`) y almacenar el resultado en una nueva variable.

```
TempA     humedad    TemB

20          52      22
42          35      25 
NA          62      28
22          60      32
18          85      NA #Para los casos NA, quisiera que se conservara el 
valor registrado sin promediar
```

De tal manera que el resultado sea:

```
TempA     humedad    TemB     TempC

20          52      22         21
42          35      25         33.5
NA          62      28         28
22          60      32         27
18          85      NA         18
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumiendo que tus datos se llaman `datos`

```
datos <- structure(list(TempA = c(20, 42, NA, 22, 18), 
                        humedad = c(52, 35, 62, 60, 85), 
                        TempB = c(22, 25, 28, 32, NA)), 
                        class = "data.frame", 
                        row.names = c(NA, -5L))

datos$TempC <- apply(datos[ ,c(1,3)], 1, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

## Explicación

`apply` aplica una función a una matriz o data frame. En este caso es al data frame `datos` en las columnas 1 y 3 con `datos[ , c(1,3)]`. Es importante es espacio antes de la coma, eso significa que se va a aplicar la función a todas las filas. El número `1` le indica a `apply` que debe operar por filas. Con `2` aplicaría la función por columnas.

La función que aplicamos es `mean`, que calcula la media. A pasarle el argumento `na.rm = TRUE` ignora los valores perdidos en el cálculo de la media. Por defect con `na.rm = FALSE` regresa `NA` cuando un vector contiene al menos un valor `NA`.

Por último con `<-` asignamos el output resultante de `apply` (un vector) a una nueva columna llamada `TempC` del data frame `datos`.

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma "base" bastante performante es usar directamente [`rowMeans()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/colSums.html)

```
df$TempC <- rowMeans(df[, c(1,3)], na.rm = TRUE)
df

  TempA humedad TemB TempC
1    20      52   22  21.0
2    42      35   25  33.5
3    NA      62   28  28.0
4    22      60   32  27.0
5    18      85   NA  18.0
```